# @SessionScoped cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am using `@SessionScoped` in my managed bean and it gives me the error.

> @SessionScoped cannot be resolved to a type

What am I missing?

Relevant code:

```
package javaeetutorial.guessnumber;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Random;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserNumberBean implements Serializable {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Show your relevant code, including all `import` statements.

Comment: So import it. Your IDE can do that automatically.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I have hit control+shift+o and nothing happens. I've done the import recommended below and it says that javax.enterprise cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the import below,

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
```

In the future your can always use you IDE to resolve the imports for you, ctrl+shift+o in eclipse.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Odd, it's saying that javax.enterprise cannot be resolved

Comment: You might be missing a dependency in your pom file, try adding
   
 `<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
   <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: @ivanorone what if I don't have a pom file?

Answer (score -1):

Add the Faces library instead:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
```